# Youtube API require paths

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Why the paths are hardcoded ? For example:

```
require_once 'Zend/Gdata/Extension.php';
```

The thing is that `Zend` folder is not in root - it's in `library/packages`

So do I have to change the path of every file?
To be like :

```
define('ROOT_PACKAGES', dirname(__FILE__) . "/library/packages/");

ROOT_PACKAGE.'Zend/Gdata/Extension.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain by asking you a question. When you use 'Zend/Gdata/Extension.php' - what directory is it looking in for the sub-directory Zend? You will answer "/library/packages/" and that leads to the key question. **Why?**

**Update:** My question is not why use that directory, it's why would the O/S have that directory as the default directory.

At any point in time there is a default directory. And relative paths will then be evaluated using that default directory. But the value of that is not locked to a specific directory. And it is dependent on how an app is running. I assume you have a web app and basically any code in your app, or the web server, can change the directory.

So yes, use ROOT_PACKAGES. You should always use fully qualified directories.

Comment: The web app is using MVP thats why the Zend folder have to be in library/packages not in the root where the index.php file is.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my "why?". It was not why do you put them in that directory, it's why would the O/S use that directory as the default directory. The problem you are hitting is that is not the default directory. Sorry for the confusion in my answer.